# Ребята, я пытался переписать этот код с С++ на С#, но зашел в тупик. Может кто-то знает что делать?

Tags: c#, c++

На С++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 srand(time(NULL));
 int i,j;
 int c[25];
 int z;
 int y;
 cout << "input y: "<< endl;
 cin >> y;
 cout <<"matrix C: "<< endl;
int ar[5][5];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  ar[i][j] = rand()%100;
  cout << setw(4) << ar[i][j];
 }
 cout << endl;
}
int x = 0;
z = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  if (ar[i][j] < y) {
   c[z] = ar[i][j];
   z += 1;
   x += 1;
   }   
 }
}
int sum= 1;
int temp;
cout << "mass D:" << endl;
for (z = 0; z < x; z++) {
 cout << setw(3) << c[z];
}
for(z =0; z< x; z++)
 sum*= c[z];
cout << endl<< "sum = " << sum;
for (i =0; i < x -1; i++){ 
for (j=0; j<x - i - 1; j++) {
 if (c[j] > c[j +1]) {
  temp = c[j];
  c[j] =c[j +1];
  c[j+1] = temp;
 }
}
}
cout << endl<< " sort mass D:" << endl;
for (z = 0; z < x; z ++) {
 cout << setw(3) << c[z];
} 
}
```

На С#

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
                    int[,] C = new int[5,5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    C[i,j] = rnd.Next();//заполняем рандомно 
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", C[i,j]);//вывод массива 
                                    }
                Console.WriteLine();
                 int n; 
      Console.Write("Ввести значение y:");
      n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      for (int k = 0; k < n; i++);
            }   
        int[,] D = new int[3,3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    C[i,j] = rnd.Next();//заполняем рандомно 
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", D[i,j]);//вывод матрицы
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: А проблема в чем?

Comment: Эта строка `Random rnd = new Random();` должна быть не внутри цикла, а снаружи, сделайте ее приватным статическим полем;